# Grails OpenId Plugin Error

Tags: grails, spring-security, buildconfig

I am trying to do the tutorial of the Grails openId plugin. I created a test app and followed exactly the steps from the tutorial of Burt Beckwith http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-openid/docs/manual/guide/3.%20Tutorials.html

But when I am already on the steps of doing this:
$ grails s2-quickstart com.openidtest User Role

it displays an error:

Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- com.google.code.guice:guice:2.0

Can someone please tell me why? I already added this to the BuildConfig.groovy: mavenRepo "http://guice-maven.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/" but it still doesnt work.

Please help, thank you

Comment: Just tried to open this mavenRepo, it asks for password and doesn't work for anonymous user

Answer (score 3):

Guice 2 is in Maven Central but under a different group ID.  You may be able to get it working by declaring the plugin in BuildConfig instead of using `install-plugin` so you can exclude the transitive dependency

```
plugins {
  compile(':spring-security-openid:1.0.4') {
    excludes 'guice'
  }
}
```

and then pull in the right dependency explicitly in the dependencies section

```
dependencies {
  compile('com.google.inject:guice:2.0')
```

Comment: This worked for me with Grails 2.2.4 and plugins.spring-security-openid 1.0.4

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line to the 'repositories' section of the buildConfig.groovy file fixed it for me.

mavenRepo "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-uploads/"

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYOPENID-23 - I'm working on a fix.

Comment: Turns out guice [is in Maven Central after all](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14749921/592139)...